# GWT StackPanel Styling

Tags: css, gwt, stackpanel

I guess this should be straight forward, except I just can't figure it out.  I'm trying to use a stackpanel.  I'm trying to style it so that the header's text, background color, etc matches the rest of my app.

I'm using css and a client bundle to apply styles to my components.

I've tried to style the stackpanel using two methods and both have failed.

### Method1:

If I apply the following to the MyProject.html style section:

```
.gwt-StackPanel .gwt-StackPanelItem {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}


.gwt-StackPanel .gwt-StackPanelItem-selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And then load it in firefox, I still see the default styling.  If I open up firebug and inspect the element, I see that the gwt default styles are still being applied.

### Method 2:

If I encapsulate the above styles in my css file then GWT compiler complains about obfuscated styles?  So I added the @external attrib to the styles, the compiler doesn't complain, but I still don't see my changes applied.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer, but in case someone comes here later I have a suggestion. The reason your CSS gets overridden by the gwt theme is that the gwt theme is taking precident in your module file (.gwt.xml). The way to change this is to include your own CSS file in your module file after the gwt theme.

For example, you should see something like this in your module file:

```
<!-- You can change the theme of your GWT application by -->
<!-- uncommenting any one of the following lines. -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />
```

Somewhere after this, add a stylesheet statement for you own css file:

```
<!-- CSS Style Sheet includes -->
<stylesheet src="<pathToYourCSSFile>.css" />
```

Now, because your file is included after the gwt style, your styles will take precedent over gwt!

Answer (score 1):

I always comment out this line from the xml file of the module:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

then you can use your own styles adding stylenames to widgets (stackPanel.setStyle...)
And if you need a default style of gwt you can copy it from gwt-user.jar `com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard.public.gwt.standard.standard.css` to your own css file.

Comment: Thanks for this...I just ended up not using the stack panel, but next time I use it, I'll try this out!